# Automatic Airbrake errors with plain Ruby (no Rails or Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, rack, airbrake

Is there a way to integrate Airbrake with a pure Ruby project (not rails or sinatra) so that unanticipated errors get reported?  I have it set up and I am able to catch errors by calling `Airbrake.notify_or_ignore` and passing in the exception, but I can't get it to report errors without explicitly calling this.

The following is the code that works for explicitly calling `Airbrake.notify` but doesn't work for sending errors to Airbrake without explicitly calling `notify`:

```
require 'airbrake'

Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['AIRBRAKE_API_KEY']
  config.development_environments = []
  config.ignore_only = []
end
```

I tried adding Rack as a middleware with the following code:

```
require 'rack'
require 'airbrake'


Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = ENV['AIRBRAKE_API_KEY']
  config.development_environments = []
  config.ignore_only = []
end


app = Rack::Builder.app do
    run lambda { |env| raise "Rack down" }
end

use Airbrake::Rack
run app
```

But I get an "undefined method `use' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

Any thoughts?

Comment: It took me all of 30 seconds to find examples of using Airbrake in plain ruby: https://help.airbrake.io/kb/api-2/v2-api-projects-and-groups

Comment: The snippet above is for Rack application. Airbrake has a wiki page about how to use it with plain ruby: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/wiki/Using-Airbrake-with-plain-Ruby

Answer (score -1):

Copied from Mark's comment's link to airbrake for future googlers:

```
# code at http://gist.github.com/3350
# tests at http://gist.github.com/3354

class Airbrake < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://your_account.airbrake.io"

  class << self
    @@auth_token = 'your_auth_token'

    def find(*arguments)
      arguments = append_auth_token_to_params(*arguments)
      super(*arguments)
    end

    def append_auth_token_to_params(*arguments)
      opts = arguments.last.is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
      opts = opts.has_key?(:params) ? opts : opts.merge(:params => {}) 
      opts[:params] = opts[:params].merge(:auth_token => @@auth_token)
      arguments << opts
      arguments
    end
  end
end

class Error < Airbrake  
end

# Errors are paginated. You get 30 at a time.

@errors = Error.find :all
@errors = Error.find :all, :params => { :page => 2 }
```